# calculate E[X^n] with moment generating function

Tags: moment-generating-functions

Say random variable X has a density function $ f(x)=1 $ when $0<x<1$. So this means $E[X^n]= \int_0^1 x^n.1 dx = \frac{1}{n+1}$.

At the same time we can get that the moment generation function $\phi(t)$ of random variable $X$ as $\phi(t)=\frac{e^t-1}{t}$

I know the $n^{th}$ derivation of $\phi(t)$ is $E[X^n]$ but how can I show $\phi^n(t)=\frac{1}{n+1}$

Comment: Write out the Taylor series for $\phi(t)$ using the Taylor series for $e^t$.

Comment: That make sense. One doubt I have is (may be due to my lack of understanding of the Taylor series) Is the Taylor series for both $e^t$ and $e^t.t^{-1}$ the same?

Comment: No. You take the Taylor series for $e^t$, then subtract $1$, then divide by $t$.

Answer (score 3):

You cant show that, what you can show is that $\phi ^{(n)}(0) = \frac{1}{n+1}$ and in general you have $\mathbb{E}[X^k]= \phi ^{(k)}(0)$.

As written in the comments uyou could easily show that using the Taylor sum of $e^t$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

If $\phi(t)$ denotes the [moment generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function) of $X$ then:$$\phi(t)=1+\frac{\mathbb EX.t}{1!}+\cdots\frac{\mathbb EX^n.t^n}{n!}+\cdots$$

If $\phi(t)=\frac{e^t-1}t$ then:$$\phi(t)=1+\frac{t}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{t^n}{(n+1)!}+\cdots$$